# Can a web app in UIWebView gain access to native storage

Tags: ipad, web-applications, uiwebview, iphone-web-app

If I have a web app running in a UIWebView can the javascript context in the web app get any sort of access to data in the native ipad app context?  I'd like to store lots of images in the native app database, then access these from a web app running in a UIWebView within the native app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not directly, but if you can get some kind of "bridge" working with Javascript, you can use native code to pass back paths to files and such. Look into the the `stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"SomeJSCommandHere"`. Check out [this webpage](http://www.codingventures.com/2008/12/using-uiwebview-to-render-svg-files/) for more information on that. It looks like they discuss it.